# cannot connect to a soap api with php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, uri

I'm trying to access this URI: `http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL` (Dell warranty info)

In Windows Powershell I can do this no problem:

```
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL
```

But in PHP:

```
$DELL_URL = "http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL"; //Access webproxy by IP
$soap = new SoapClient($DELL_URL);

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL' in C:\path\to\my\script.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\path\to\my\script.php(25): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://143.166....') #1 {main} thrown in C:\path\to\my\script.php on line 25
```

What am I doing wrong in php? I know the URL works cause it works with powershell.

As per Pete's suggestion I went to `http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL` and downloaded a local copy of the file then did this which worked:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdlfilepath);
```

Do I always have to download a local copy of the file when using php?

edit: Didn't make any changes but now I'm getting "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in..." error. Should I be worried about this? You can view the wsdl file by going to the link. Are there problems with it or extra white space? I didn't see any.

Comment: Does it work if you download the WSDL and instantiate a new SoapClient using the local copy?

Comment: That worked. I updated my post. So will I always have to download a local copy of the file first when using PHP?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. It probably means you have one of the issues discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp

Comment: If that solves the issue, can you either mark your question as a duplicate of the link I provided or post your resolution here as an answer and then accept it (accept your own answer)? Thanks!