# PHP SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl,array("trace" => true, "exceptions" => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
```

I get this error :

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxx.xxx.com/HotelFlow.svc/bas' : failed to load external entity "http://xxx.xxx.com/HotelFlow.svc/bas

I tried this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/2942945
but I still get the same error message

$wsdl is not a https link

If I do in command line

```
wget http://xxx.xxx.com/HotelFlow.svc/bas
```

I get this message

Connecting to xxx.xxx.com|204.204.204.204|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2016-06-10 12:34:58 ERROR 400: Bad Request.