# Symfony2 using SoapClient

Tags: symfony, soap

I have a symfony2 project and it throws this error on this code exactly

```
$c = new \SoapClient($objWidget->getLink() . '/ws.php?wsdl');
```

`$objwidget` is not empty and here is the error

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "SoapClient" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?"

I tried use `SoapClient` at the top but still issue with `SoapClient`.

Comment: check that the library is correctly installed http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php

Comment: thank you i enabled ssl soap in php.inf but now i have this error 
Uncaught PHP Exception SoapFault: "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'Adress' : failed to load external entity "Adress"

Comment: ok now you can debug the situations as example as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/2270041

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Soap not installet globally like other modules in PHP !
Jus install it ! default **apt-get install php-soap**
for example if use php v5.6

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6-soap
```

or if your php v 7.1

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.1-soap
```

e t.c.

then EXACTLY reload you server + CLEAR SymFony cache !!!

```
service apache2 reload
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```