# soapClient in symfony 3

Tags: php, soap, symfony, soap-client

I‌ want to use SoapClient but seems that it is missing! because I got this Error:
`Attempted to load class "SoapClient" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?`
The soap extensions is enabled.
php v7.0.14

Comment: What does your client code look like? Is it like this: `$client = new \Soapclient(...`  Notice the backslash "\". Posting some of your code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/43488893/5809937

but when it installed, does it properly displays in phpinfo()(like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391550/5809937) ?

- don't forget to **clear symfony cache** (manually or thru CLI-console)  + restart apache !