# PHP SOAP client over IPv4

Tags: php, soap, ipv6, soap-client, ipv4

I have a PHP client that needs to connect to a SOAP server:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('url_to_wsdl.wsdl', [
                'local_cert' => 'path_to_certificate.pem', 
                'connection_timeout ' => 300,
                'trace' => 1,
            ]);

$params = [];
$response = $client->executeAFunction($params);
```

But the SOAP client can't connect to the host: `SoapFault "Could not connect to host"` (it actually can't load the wsdl file either, but I mocked that by using a local copy of the file).

I came to the point where I figured out the Soap client cannot connect to the host because it seemingly uses IPv6 by default (I got to this point because of [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/1114204)).

What have I done so far:

- I already disabled IPv6 on my server (ubuntu), but that didn't change
  anything to the SOAP client.
- I double-checked the reachability of websites over both IPv4 and IPv6 via the servers terminal

  ```
  $ curl -6 http://v6.testmyipv6.com/
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: v6.testmyipv6.com

  $ curl -4 http://v4.testmyipv6.com/
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>IPv6 Test and Dual-Stack Test For Network Connectivity</title>
  ...

  # the above commands are true for all urls I tested
  ```

**My actual question is: how can I tell the Soap client to connect to the host using IPv4 instead of using IPv6?**

Comment: Check the DNS records. If the server isn't reachable over IPv6 then there must not be any AAAA records.

Comment: @SanderSteffann there is no AAAA record, that is the problem... The system can reach the server but tries to look it up over IPv6 resulting in a 'could not connect to host' fault.

Comment: Clients use IPv6 by default only if there is an IPv6 address known. If there is no IPv6 address then clients fall back to IPv4 unless you force a specific protocol in some other way (like you did with curl). You must be having a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SOAP request is a socket connection, so you can use socket_context options.
Use `stream_context_create()` to bind your request to a specified IP.

```
stream_context_create(['socket' => ['bindto' => '123.123.123.123:0']]);
```

Set `0` for port number so PHP will set this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than binding to a specific IPv4 IP address, you can also substitute the IP address with `0`:

```
stream_context_create(['socket' => ['bindto' => '0:0']]);
```

A full example of forcing IPv4 for a SoapClient might be:

```php
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'Your/UserAgent'
    ),
    'socket' => ['bindto' => '0:0']
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$soapClientOptions = array(
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'trace' => true,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
```