# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] in php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from "url" failed to load external entity.

I am getting below error when used `SoapClient` in the code. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the URL to the SOAP service you require, and that it does indeed serve a wsdl (add `?wsdl` to the end of the URL and inspect in a browser).

It sounds like your SOAP Service URL is missing a WSDL (service discovery) or is not finding a valid SOAP endpoint.

If you care to share your SOAP URL I can provide example or I/others might be able to help more.

Could also be character encoding or User Agent filtering on the SOAP endpoint, have a read of this question : [SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from - but works on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp)