# soap error when using artisaninweb/laravel-soap to call a soap web service in a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have developed a project with `Laravel` framework that uses  `artisaninweb/laravel-soap` to call a `soap` web service and it worked fine on a host. Since I have moved my web project from the host to a CentOS server, it can not call the soap web service and gets following error and I can not understand the reason.

```
SoapFault
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://x.x.org:x/?wsdl' :
failed to load external entity "http://x.x.org:x/?wsdl"
```

Of course I have installed `curl`,`openssl` and `soap` modules and my server has access to soap web service.Is there any configuration that must be done?

Comment: Please see  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp)

Comment: I checked the mentioned link but it couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with running this command on the server.

```
 sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```