# Lravel :SoapFault SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://mydomain.ir/webservice/url/send.php?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: laravel, sms, soap-client

im trying to make notification service in laravel...
in `config/services.php` I added this array:

```
'sms-panel' => [
    'Username' =>env('SMS_USER_NAME'),
    'Password' =>env('SMS_PASSWORD'),
    'fromNum' =>env('SMS_NUM'),
    'Type' => 0,

    'uri'=>env('SMS_API_LINK'),
],
```

and in `.env` file added this:

```
SMS_USER_NAME=username
SMS_PASSWORD=password
SMS_NUM="+985000xxx"
SMS_API_LINK=http://mydomain.ir/webservice/url/send.php?wsdl
```

and created `Services/Notification.php` class and have a method named sendSms in it :

```
class Notification
{

    public function sendSms(User $user, string $text)
    {
        
        //$soap=new SoapClient("http://mydomain.ir/webservice/send.php?wsdl");//insert directly
        $url=config('services.sms-panel.uri');
        $soap=new SoapClient($url);

        $soap->Username = config('services.sms-panel.Username');
        $soap->Password = config('services.sms-panel.Password');
        $soap->fromNum = config('services.sms-panel.fromNum');
        $soap->toNum = array($user->phone_number);
        $soap->Content = $text;
        $soap->Type = '0';
        $array = $soap->SendSMS($soap->fromNum, $soap->toNum, $soap->Content, $soap->Type, $soap->Username, $soap->Password);
        var_dump($array);


    }
}
```

and when I try to create new `SoapClient` and get URI from config getting this error:

> SoapFault SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
> 'http://mydomain.ir/webservice/url/send.php?wsdl' : Start tag
> expected, '<' not found

but when directly paste the link(commented line) it works perfectly.

and this is the result of `dd($url)` or `dd(cconfig('services.sms-panel.uri'))`:

"http://mydomain.ir/webservice/url/send.php?wsdl"

Comment: Please try like this `$soap=new SoapClient({$url});`

Comment: @maki10  it causes syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: Can you `dd` this `config('services.smspanel.uri')`? I think that you have typo in `smspanel` in a config is `sms-panel`..

Comment: I've added the result of dd()... that typo is in this question and not in code

Comment: Try disable soap cache like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480002/3740460

Comment: still same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218498/discussion-between-mohammadreza-khalifeh-and-maki10).